# game data transfer from on account to another

Tags: clash-of-clans

I play clash of clan on my mom s account now I have my own account so I want to transfer the game data from my moms account to my account I am using android so google+ please help.

Comment: The game links its save data to google+ accounts. I don't think you can actually transfer between accounts.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to transfer data between several accounts. The only thing possible normally is data transfer between devices if you use the same account.